# How can I install `mpich` library?

Tags: 16.04, compiling

How can I install `mpich` library? I tried [compiling WRF](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php) but I could not install it.

Comment: "I could not install it" is a big vague. Exactly which step failed? How exactly did it fail? What have you researched about that failure message?

Comment: `libmpich12` / `libmpich-dev` version 3.2 should be available from the 16.04 universe repository

Comment: tar xzvf mpi-3.0.4.tar.gz
    cd mpich-3.0.4
    ./configure --prefix=$DIR/mpich
    make
    make install
    export PATH=$DIR/mpich/bin:$PATH
    cd ..             these how I try user535733

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Go to http://www.mpich.org/downloads/ and click on `Xenial` for Ubuntu 16.04. This takes you here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mpich. Then click on `amd64` and you are here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/mpich/download. Where it says:

> If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package
>   manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages,
>   instead of doing so manually via this website.

So instead of installing manually, use:

```
$ sudo apt install mpich
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cpp-5 g++-5 gcc-5 gcc-5-base gfortran gfortran-5 hwloc-nox libasan2 libatomic1
  libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcr-dev libcr0 libgcc-5-dev libgfortran-5-dev libgfortran3
  libgomp1 libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpich-dev libmpich12 libmpx0
  libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6 libtsan0 libubsan0
Suggested packages:
  gcc-5-locales g++-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libstdc++6-5-dbg gcc-5-multilib libgcc1-dbg
  libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg gfortran-multilib
  gfortran-doc gfortran-5-multilib gfortran-5-doc libgfortran3-dbg blcr-dkms
  libhwloc-contrib-plugins libstdc++-5-doc blcr-util mpich-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gfortran gfortran-5 hwloc-nox libcr-dev libcr0 libgfortran-5-dev libhwloc-plugins
  libhwloc5 libmpich-dev libmpich12 mpich
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-5 g++-5 gcc-5 gcc-5-base libasan2 libatomic1 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libgcc-5-dev
  libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6
  libtsan0 libubsan0
19 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 213 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 39.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

At this point click `y` to install the package.

***There is no need to compile from source like you were attempting to do.***